# How to save screen shot of a web page?

Tags: macos, webpage-screenshot

I want to save screen shot of a web page.But I don't know how.Just like the app [delish](https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/delish/id504472899?mt=12).In delish ,when i add a bookmark ,the app capture the website and save it such as p5.delish.I guess the screenshot comes from the file of the ".delish".How can i produce this file? or some one has some samples like this app? Thanke you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIWebThumbnail/

> ASIWebThumbnail is:
>
> - A command line tool for generating thumbnails from web pages
> - An API to use an embedded version of the tool in your Cocoa applications
>
> ASIWebThumbnail uses the WebKit framework built-in Mac OS X to render web pages. As such, it should support any content that WebKit supports, including HTML/XML + CSS, SVG, content rendered by Javascript (Canvas, AJAX, DOM etc), Java, as well as Flash and other plugins.

Comment: Could you tell me your email that you uesd to ? I wanna to communicate with you about osx questions. There are few people who program with osx in my country.

Comment: I download this sample and run !I find that it produces images very slowly.Why? This sample is based in 10.5 SDK.

Comment: That's probably because rendering the image has to wait until all resources are loaded, which might take a couple of seconds. Google.com is done after around one second for me.

Comment: I am new about osx! I also want to know how to produce the .app file like the delish.

Comment: I change the urls in the code.These urls is easy to open in my brower.But the sample still run a long time and nothing to produce.I don't know why

Comment: It seems it doesn't produce anything if you just type the domain name (google.com); you need to specify the whole url, e.g. "http://www.google.com/".

Comment: I tried the ASIWebThumbnail.I found that it produced the image that the page is white in some positions. suc as Taobao(http://www.taobao.com) Why? How can i improve it? thank u

Comment: The command line tool says <Error>: clip: empty path. Might be related. Look at the code that throws this error, and if you can't figure out where it is breaking, ask another Stackoverflow question containing what you tried to do and what doesn't work.

Comment: I code a demo.But it still has some problems.I have already ask another Stackoverflow question.Hava a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051007/how-to-take-a-screenshot-when-a-webview-finished-rending)